# Verilog module cannot calculate a&b and a|b

Tags: verilog, iverilog

I am creating the verilog module that calculate either one of a+b, a-b, a & b or a | b.

The problem is that it does calculate for a+b and a-b.
but it cannot calculate a & b and a | b and return nothing.

```
input [31:0] a, b;
input [2:0] op;
output [31:0] z;
output ex; 
wire[31:0]a0,a1,a2,a3;

assign a0 = a & b;
assign a1 = a | b;
assign a2 = a + b;
assign a3 = a - b;

assign z=a0;
//assign z=a1;
//assign z=a2;
//assign z=a3;

endmodule
```

the module basically calculate a+b, a-b, a&b, and a|b and assign its calculated value to z.

And it does successfully calculate for a+b and a-b and put calculated value to z.

But for a&b and a|b, it doesn't assign anything to z.

How can I solve this?

Thank you very much if you can help me.

Comment: I [put a delay after setting input](http://codepad.org/xCv3b5N8) and it seems working well. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it does assign something to `z`. The problem is that you are trying to assign too much to `z`.

Each `assign` statement represents some hardware, which in this case drives the `wire` `z`. So, you are driving `z` 4 times *in parallel* from 4 separate lumps of hardware. If you like, you have a short circuit. (Remember Verilog is a *hardware* description language. You are designing *hardware* here, not writing *software*. If you assign to a wire from more than one place, you have shorted the outputs of some lumps of hardware together.)

I notice there is an `input [2:0] op`. This looks like homework to me and I guess you have been asked to design an ALU. An ALU is a lump of hardware (combinational logic in this case) that can perform various operations on it's inputs (its *operands*), which in this case are `a` and `b`. Which operation it performs needs to be selected by some other control input, which in this case is almost certainly supposed to be `op`.

So, you need some code that tests `op` and drives `z` with either `a+b`, `a-b`, `a&b` or `a|b`. The obvious construct to me for this job is a `case` statement:

```
case (op)
  3'b000:
    z =     // some expression, eg a + b, it depends on what op code 000 is supposed to mean
  3'b001:
    z =     // some other expression here

            // etc etc

  default:  // perhaps...
    z =     // ...something to drive z if none of the other branches are used
endcase
```

A `case` statement should go inside an `always` block. As I suspect this is homework, I won't feed you the answer, I'll let you work out how to do that.

Finally, I see that `op` is 3 bits wide. This suggests that you ALU has more than 4 different operations to carry out. I also see there is an `ex` output, which presumably needs to do something.

Answer (score 0):

There's some confusion here. Your original posted code is fine; `z` will be assigned as you want. The other answer is incorrect - there are no multiple drivers; they're commented out. The delay suggestion is also incorrect - a delay will make no difference whatever to your logic.